# Eclipse can't build on big XML file

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I've build an Android Hangman app that works fine on an XML list of words that contains 10 items. Now I want to use a more exhaustive list of words (around 23000 items), but when trying to build Eclipse hangs at 25% with no progress showing in over 15 minutes. Is this a known issue and is there a simple solution?

Comment: You'd better put your strings in a database table!

Comment: Assuming it needs 1s to compile 10 entrys, it will take 2300s to compile this much.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? What is actually hanging?